# Why am I allowed to use New on a class with no accessible New method?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, constructor

According to Object Browser, the PISDKCommon.NamedValues class has no accessible New method.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa748.png

However, Visual Studio allows me to use "New PISDKCommon.NamedValues" with no error or warning.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxzF4.png

What does this mean?

Edit: The comments and answers I'm getting essentially amount to "*The class **does** have an accessible New method*". I am going to remain skeptical of  this answer until someone can explain to me why a class with an accessible New method doesn't show that method in the Object Browser.

Comment: If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided

Comment: The default constructor is available as long as there is no other constructor.

Comment: @magnus and tim-schmelter: If a default constructor is automatically provided for PISDKCommon.NamedValues, then why can't I see the automatically-provided constructor in the Object Browser? Can I infer that the Object Browser omits members under such circumstances?

Comment: @T.C. as you know a constructor is a special method, and your assumption is safe in that case.

Comment: @dan-verdolino: Thank you, but I'm having trouble squaring all the facts. If I create a class with no constructor declaration, that class appears in the Object Browser with a New() method. PISDKCommon.NamedValues, on the other hand, appears in the Object Browser without a New() method. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Given the other types appearing alongside the one that you're looking at in the object browser, I suspect that what you're actually looking at is a [COM Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxz80y2(v=vs.110).aspx). Those have all kinds of quirkiness going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

From [Passing Data to a Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx#creatingclasses_topic7)

"The constructor method is called New in Visual Basic .NET. By default, Visual Basic .NET creates this New method for you without you having to do anything. You won't see this code within your code module, but it is there implicitly. If you wish to pass some data to this New method, you need to explicitly create it."